# Google Analytics Ionic 3 (Ionic View)

Tags: ionic-framework, google-analytics, ionic3

Installed Google Analytics using this tutorial:

https://www.javascripttuts.com/introduction-to-ionic-google-analytics/

I've installed the dependencies and have put the code into my constructor using my tracking code.

I'm exporting my app to test with Ionic View. Does Google analytics work with Ionic View? I can't seem to get it working or find references for it...

Comment: Yes, it should work. Check your google-analytics real time section to see if there is any activity there.

Comment: Cant seem to get anything in the real-time section either. Interesting that the tutorial I followed has the code within the constructor, but the reference by ionic framework has it outside of the constructor and in a function. Would this be the case? @ari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tutorial [Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/add-google-analytics-in-ionic-3-application-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugin/)**

[How to Get Google Tracking ID for Mobile Devices?](http://www.freakyjolly.com/add-google-analytics-in-ionic-3-application-using-cordova-and-ionic-native-plugin/)

Install Plugin

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-analytics
```

In **app.component.ts** file call following method

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXXXXXXX-X')
  .then(() => {}).catch(e => alert('Error starting GoogleAnalytics == '+ e));

});
```

Make sure you have included the plugin in **app.module.ts** file providers array

In List page ad **trackView** and **trackEvent** method as shown below

```
...

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.ga.trackView('List Page')
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }


  itemTapped(event, item) {
    this.ga.trackEvent('Category', 'Tapped Action', 'Item Tapped is '+item, 0);
    // That's right, we're pushing to ourselves!
    this.navCtrl.push(ListPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }

...
```

Comment: This is useful for native app. If using as PWA or Web, then answer mentioned by "Ari Waisberg" helps. Best will be to combine both so it will work on native +PWA

Answer (score 3):

I've seen that Ionic's Google Analytics Plugin is not working, and the Android SDK is being deprecated, so I implemented like this:

In the Index.html file insert this code just after  or

```
  <script>
    (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
              i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
              i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                  (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
              }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
              a = s.createElement(o),
                  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
              a.async = 1;
              a.src = g;
              m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
          })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  </script>
```

OBVIOUSLY replace the "UA-xxxxxx-x" code with yours...

And then, in every page you want to measure just add this in **ionViewDidEnter** method of .TS File you want:

```
(<any>window).ga('set', 'page', 'MyPageName');
(<any>window).ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The only thing to change is "MyPageName", the rest leave it that way.

If you want to track an event just add this code to that event:

```
(<any>window).ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'eventCategory',
      eventLabel: 'eventLabel',
      eventAction: 'eventAction',
      eventValue: 10
    });
```

Replacing Category, Label, and Action for what you want to measure...

It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

### **Google analytics Ionic 3**

Install this plugin

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-google-analytics
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-analytics
```

[Create track Id in your google developement console.](https://console.developers.google.com/)

*import in your app.module.ts and home.ts*

```
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
```

**Home.ts**

```
    export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private googleAnalytics: GoogleAnalytics) {

  }
  google(){
    this.googleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('XXXXXXXXX', 30)
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
        this.googleAnalytics.trackView('Screen Title')
        .then(()=>{
          console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.log("Faild"+ e)
        })

        this.googleAnalytics.trackView('Screen Title', 'my-scheme://content/1111?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=my-campaign')
        .then(()=>{
          console.log("Success 1")
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.log("Faild 1" + e)
        })

        this.googleAnalytics.trackEvent('Category', 'Action', 'Label', 30)
        .then(()=>{
          console.log("Success Event");
        })
        .catch(()=>{
          console.log("Faild")
        })

        this.googleAnalytics.trackMetric(5)
        .then(()=>{
          console.log("Key Matrics run successfully");
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.log("Faild" + e)
        })

        this.googleAnalytics.trackTiming('Category', 2, 'Variable', 'Label')
        .then(()=>{
          console.log("TrackTiming success")
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.log("Faild"+ e)
        })
     // Tracker is ready
     // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId
     this.googleAnalytics.debugMode();
     this.googleAnalytics.setAllowIDFACollection(true);
   })
   .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
  }
  // GTM-5SFPKBZ
}
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Do I have to call the function? Or just having it there will fire off and record?

Comment: Or do I have to put it in the constructor? That's my hang up cause in the ionic documentation it has it like you have it as well. I just can't get it called in the console @edison-j

Comment: You have have to call the function.I have that function in the button click event.